# Appended element reports wrong height

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

I am appending a modal dialog window to my page

```
$('body').append('<div id="modalBackdrop" style="z-index: 1000; display: none;"></div><div id="modalContent">' + $(content).html() + '</div>');
```

then I do

```
var modalContent = $('#modalContent');
var mdcTop = modalContent.height();
console.log(mdcTop);
$('#modalBackdrop').css(css).css('top', 0).css('height', docHeight + 'px').css('width', docWidth + 'px').show();
modalContent.css({'margin-top': -mdcTop + 'px'}).hide()[animation](speed);
```

**HERE IS THE FULL SCRIPT: http://jsfiddle.net/2jdrp/**

The weird thing is, Web Developer tools reports height as: **393.25px** but console.log reports **91**...

That's the actual loaded HTML content of the modal dialog:

```
<div id="modalContent" style="margin-top: -91px; display: block;">    <div class="ctools-modal-content" style="width: 570px;">      <div class="modal-header">        <a class="close" href="#"><img src="http://10.0.146.120/profiles/paddle/themes/paddle_admin/images/icon-close-window.png" alt="Close window" title="Close window">        </a>        <span id="modal-title" class="modal-title">Create new menu</span>      </div>      <div id="modal-content" class="modal-content" style="width: 545px;"><form action="/admin/structure/menu_manager/ajax/add" method="post" id="paddle-menu-manager-menu-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="ctools-use-modal-processed"><div><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-title">
  <label for="edit-title">Title <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" id="edit-title" name="title" value="" size="40" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
<div class="description">Enter the title of your menu.</div>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-description">
  <label for="edit-description">Description </label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea id="edit-description" name="description" cols="50" rows="4" class="form-textarea"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
<div class="description">Enter a short description of your menu.</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Save" class="form-submit"><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-hA5i4CZsTuBPITxX89QZr2NvtrCxexBixbjTGsr1taE">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="13r4DJkBshuYXq9t9cG5U5IPwUaIdU0W4xYPx9naHXQ">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="paddle_menu_manager_menu_form">
</div></form></div>    </div>  </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about if you use outerHeight instead of height? on var mdcTop = modalContent.outerHeight(true);

Comment: What exactly are you looking at in web tools that shows the height = to 393.25px?

Comment: computed values, I'll add a printscreen

Comment: If your modalContent  contents images, you have to wait for them to be loaded too

Comment: no images, only a form.

Comment: for what purpose you will require height, to set modal height same as content to remove the scroll bars?

Comment: to set height of the modal sam e as its content , you can use callback functionality which will set height perfectly

Comment: could you please clarify your answer with normal code/answer?

Answer (score 0):

what about if you use outerHeight instead of height?

```
var mdcTop = modalContent.outerHeight(true);
```

Comment: you are going to need to give us more than a few screenshots and an explanation of what the html/script is. Is there a way you can provide a URL or jsfiddle of the complete html, js and css? without it it's very unlikely anyone can pin-point the problem.

Comment: I had the impression I gave enough info but I can also give a jsfiddle - the script is only 500 lines long :)

Comment: no, all of it... everything in it's entirety including html, css and script - all together at the same time - so we can inspect all code and see if there is any css (or any other) confliction.

Comment: yeah, if you can't figure it out with this info, you just can't figure it out :) It's not the askers fault.

Comment: you have provided no css at all, so we cannot decipher what height anything should be anyway... If you are using floats on any internal elements, then they could be breaking the flow/box size of the parent element and many other reasons that could be causing your issue. There's nothing like helping others to help you, eh? I'll be moving on to helping those that actually DO want help from the public.